# powershell удалить до первой запятой

Tags: регулярные-выражения, powershell, active-directory

Есть список OU в powershell скрипте вида
OU=Учебный центр1,OU=Учебный центр,OU=gaz,OU=.root,DC=gaz,DC=local
необходимо отбросить текст до первой запятой те вот так:
OU=Учебный центр,OU=gaz,OU=.root,DC=gaz,DC=local
количество запятых в строке заранее неизвестно (по факту нужно получить родительскую OU)

Comment: Можно, конечно, и регулярное выражение применить. А можно и разбить строку в массив, используя `,` как разделитель, отбросить первое значение и собрать опять в строку, через запятую.
В любом случае, покажите Ваш собственный код, который пытается Вашу задачу решить. А здесь Вам помогут его поправить. Иначе вопрос вскоре закроют

Answer (score 1):

```
"OU=Учебный центр1,OU=Учебный центр,OU=gaz,OU=.root,DC=gaz,DC=local" -replace "[^,]*,(.*)", '$1'
```